# dynamically changing the listview based on the values entered into the textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox and a listview. The listviewis populated based on the value entered in the textbox. Suppose I am entering any name in the textbox. As I type the name in the textbox, the results in the listview should change dynamically. For example, if I am entering John in the textbox, after entering Jo, the listview should populate the results that start with Jo and if I enter h the listview should populate the results with Joh and so on. Please suggest me a solution (in c#) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the "TextChanged" event of your textbox and make it run an update on your ListView given the current text.

```
private void txtExample_textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateListView(txtExample.Text);
}
```

Be wary if your search is time-expensive as the textbox will start "lagging" (missing user keystrokes) while the search is performing.

Comment: Well, considering you didn't give us much information to go on, that was about the best I can do. You need to add an event handler to your textbox's TextChanged, you can do this programmatically or through your IDE. i.e: textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtExample_textChanged);